# Regex replace h1 tag with h2 tag globally with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

I'm having a hard time trying to replace `<h1>` tags with `<h2>` in a piece of content.

The closest i have gotten is this:

```
preg_replace('/<h1[\s*](class|id|style)="(.*?)">(\w*?)<\/h1>/mi', '<h2 $1="$2">$3</h2>',  $content);
```

The issue here is that a regular h1 line as:

`<h1>This is the heading</h1>`

won't get capturet.

This line:

`<h1 style="font-size:13px">Another heading</h1>`

Also won't get captured, which baffles me since it uses the same setup as class and id, only with special characters, such as `-`, `:` and so on. I thought `.*?` would cover.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something similar, taking all attributes : (every thing but > in attributes)

```
$str= <<<EOT
<h1>This is the heading</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:13px">Another heading</h1>
EOT;

$str = preg_replace('#<h1([^>]*)>(.*)</h1>#m','<h2$1>$2</h2>', $str);
print $str;
```